# ImportError: No module names atelier.fablib with Lino Developer Blog

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I set up Lino_Framework Developer blog (https://github.com/lsaffre/dblog).

After running the command $fab blog, I got the following error:
ImportError: No module names atelier.fablib

I ran a sys.append('absolute/path/to/atelier') after adding 'import sys' to fabfile.py  but it still did not work.

How do I resolve this import error?

Comment: If you just run up `python` REPL  and enter `import atelier` , what do you see?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by REPL. But I fired up python then did import atelier. I think it imported alright because nothing happened. Looks like this: >>> import atelier
>>>

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop It means running `python` in an interactive mode

Comment: if you still do not know what it is, you can search for related video in youtube. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmmUXd0AVxY

Comment: Okay. I ran python in interactive mode which resulted in >>>. I entered the following >>> import atelier. I assume it worked because the next line read >>>.

Comment: have you pressed enter after it? Is there any error message?

Comment: Yes, of course. No error messages.

Comment: Then how about `from atelier import fablib`? Also, which OS and version of python you are using?

Comment: That worked as well!

Comment: If you are using *nix system, then most likely you are starting `python` as another user and the library is not visible in that environment.

Comment: Why is this question tagged "python-sphinx"?

Comment: @mzjn The blog uses Sphinx. Here is the link to the Github repo: https://github.com/lsaffre/dblog

Comment: I didn't give all the information that you needed on the question.  I am setting up the blog on Pythonanywhere which has a Linux file system.  File residence which were cloned from Github:  ~/blog ~/atelier ~/lino ~/virtualenvs  I then created a virtual environment, pip installing all packages therein, and set up the blog as per the README.  Then when I ran ''$ fab blog'' I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of both atelier and dblog, I am clearly guilty for this problem. [Atelier](http://atelier.lino-framework.org/) has moved from fabric to [invoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/) already [more than a year ago](http://bugs.lino-framework.org/tickets/Ticket/357), and I just forgot to update the instructions at that page https://github.com/lsaffre/dblog. I'll update them asap. I apologize for the inconveniences (and welcome everybody who helps use to improve the Lino documentation).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  Unfortunately I was unable to make it work and fix it myself.  I will follow the updated tutorial.  Thanks again!